# Pass parameter to a perl script executed trough qsub

Tags: perl, pbs, qsub, torque

Hi would like to pass a parameter to my perl script that should be executed trough qsub.
So I run:

```
qsub -l nodes=node01 -v "i=500" Test.pl
```

While in Test.pl I try to call i parameter in several way:

```
use Getopt::Long;
$result = GetOptions ("i" => \$num);
open(FILE,">/data/home/FILEout.txt");
    print FILE "$num\n";             
    print FILE "$ARGV[0]";     
close(FILE);
```

Unfortunatelly output file of the perl script is always empty.

Do you have any suggestions? Where I'm wrong? Help please

Comment: What's the output from this `Test.pl`: `use Data::Dumper; open($FH,">/data/home/FILEout.txt") or die $!; local $Data::Dumper::Terse=1; local $Data::Dumper::Indent=0; print($FH Dumper(\@ARGV), "\n"); print($FH join(',', keys(%ENV)), "\n");`?

Comment: @ikegami again I really appreciate your help. The output of your Test.pl is the following: `PBS_NODEFILE,PBS_O_SHELL,PBS_O_SYSTEM,SSH_ASKPASS,PBS_O_WORKDIR,PBS_O_LANG,PBS_O_MAIL,PBS_O_PATH,LESSOPEN,PBS_JOBCOOKIE,PWD,LANG,USER,PBS_O_HOST,G_BROKEN_FILENAMES,LOGNAME,PBS_JOBID,SHLVL,INPUTRC,PATH,PBS_ENVIRONMENT,PBS_O_QUEUE,OMP_NUM_THREADS,PBS_QUEUE,HISTSIZE,PBS_O_HOME,PBS_MOMPORT,HOME,MAIL,PBS_O_LOGNAME,TZ,PBS_NODENUM,PBS_TASKNUM,NCPUS,HOSTNAME,_,LS_COLORS,SHELL,PBS_JOBNAME,PBS_JOBDIR,TMPDIR,ENVIRONMENT` using the command `qsub -l nodes=node01 -v "i=500" Test.pl`

Comment: Makes no sense potato. Is there an example like `#!/bin/sh
if [ "x" == "x$MYVAR" ] ; then
     echo "Variable is not set"
else
     echo "Variable says: $MYVAR"
fi` in your `qsub`'s docs? If so, what happens if you try that (with `-v 'MYVAR=500'`)? And what if you change `$MYVAR` to `$i` (with `-v 'i=500'`)?

Answer (score 1):

According to all documentation I can find `-v` sets an environment var, so you'd use `$ENV{i}` to get `500`. (Check your own documentation to confirm.)

---

If you wanted to actually pass an arg to your script, you could try using

```
qsub ... Test.pl -i=500
```

But based on my web search, that might only work for some versions of `qsub`. Others would require that you make a helper script (say `Test.sh`)

```
#!/bin/sh
Test.pl "-i=$i"
```

along with the command

```
qsub ... -v 'i=500' Test.sh
```

---

If `qsub ... Test.pl ...args...` is supported and you can change your script, the simplest solution is

```
qsub ... Test.pl 500
```

and

```
my ($i) = @ARGV;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm using PBRProfessional 10.4. It doesn't support `qsub ... Test.pl -i=500` and how you suggest -v sets an environment variable. So I changed my script and I add `use Env; print FILE "$ENV{i}";` but nothing changed. Do you know why? Thans again

Comment: @desmo, No, I only have the documentation to go by, and all docs I found show `-v` setting environment vars. (Note that `use Env;` doesn't do anything useful there.) I did add an alternative solution to my answer (using a helper script), but it also assumes `-v` sets environment vars.

Answer (score 0):

I Finally get the solution that works with PBRProfessional 10.4.

There are two way to solve it:

First one is the following

```
echo "perl /path/to/Test.pl -i 500" | qsub -l nodes=node06
```

Second one is two use

```
qsub -l nodes=node06 -v i=500 Test.pl
```

and read the parameter in the Test.pl through $ENV{i}